# In ReactJS how would I re-write the following code using the function as opposed to the class component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I read that it is possible to write React code using either the function or class components. For instance, the following code ...

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Test extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return ...;
  }
}

...
```

... is equivalent to this.

```
import React from 'react';

function Test() {
  return ...;
}

...
```

So, how would I re-write the following code to use the function instead?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div id="mydiv"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('mydiv'))
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried the following, but it doesn't work. Any pointers?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div id="mydiv"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
function Hello() {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('mydiv'))
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yeah, functional components don't have a `render()` method. The JSX you return from the function is what is rendered. (So remove the render method and simply just return `<h1>...</h1>`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For React functional components, this is how it should be done:

```
function Hello() {
  return <h1>Hello World!</h1>
}
```

There is no need to use the render method, as React elements are directly rendered on the return statement. You may read more about functional components on the official [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components).